# Creating test file for controller - karma + jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am learning to write test for controller in my angular app.

I have a test file which is like this

```
describe('Controller', function() {
beforeEach(module('AngularApp'));

var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('someController', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    describe('someController',function(){

      it('Testing Scope.show is defined',function() {
          expect(scope.show).toBeDefined();
  });
});

});
```

Here I test whether the scope `show` is declared.

Now I want to test whether the scope is equal to some value.

If I write a new `it` below the existing `it` I am getting this error

`A unique name is required for a Tool Definition thrown`.

```
describe('someController',function(){

  it('Testing Scope.show is defined',function() {
      expect(scope.show).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('Testing Scope.show is true',function() {
      expect(scope.show).toEqual("xyz");
  });

});
```

If I want to test the next scope value say for example 'list'.

How do I write test for that in the same file.

When I add another describe and write test I am getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: I have the same problem. the error is from textAngularSetup.js file.
@Tony Roczz - you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. to make the tests pass.
I override the constant function that throw the error. I hope this helps.

```
beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
    $provide.constant("taRegisterTool", function () { });
}));
```